# Index on view with CTE sql server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I create a view like this. Can I add an clustered index on the column "Start" and will it have any effect?

```
create view v_Weeks with SchemaBinding as 
with Periodes AS 
(
SELECT start = CONVERT(Date,'2013-08-05')
union ALL
SELECT DateAdd(day,7,start) from Periodes where start < dateadd(year,2,GETDATE())   
)
select Start,DATEADD(DAY,7,Start) as [End], datepart(ISO_WEEK,start) as week, DATEPART(YEAR,Start) as Year  from Periodes
```

Comment: The obvious suggestion would be - what happens if you *try* to add one? You have presumably already carried out that step - so, did it work, or did you get an error? And if you got an error, what did it tell you?

Comment: This is what I've tried
create unique clustered index ix_week on dbo.v_Weeks (start) 
but that's not possible, so there's not other way?

"Cannot create index on view "dbo.v_Weeks" because it references common table expression Views referencing common table expressions cannot be indexed. Consider not indexing the view, or removing the common table expression from the view definition."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a calendar table. This is exactly what you are trying to do without technically doing it.

If you just need one day per week and only for two years than you could use something like this:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20130805';
declare @thrudate date = '20150805';

create table v_Weeks (
    [Start]   date      not null primary key
  , iso_week  tinyint   not null
  , [year]    smallint  not null
  );

;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(week,@fromdate,@thrudate)+1) 
    [Date]=convert(date
          ,dateadd(week, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate)
          )
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo cross join n as tenK
  order by [Date]
)

insert into v_weeks 
select 
    Start    = [Date]
  , iso_week = datepart(iso_week,[date])
  , [year]   = datepart(year,[date])
from dates ;
```

Calendar and Numbers table references:

- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

Comment: Yes, this does what I need, almost, but the calendar need to start on the date specified and always end two year in the feature. (the table will grow with one row every 7 days)

I know I can solve it the way you suggest and create some script to add one week to the calendar every week, but I dont like "fixing scripts" to maintain a software solution and that's why I was hoping for a view with an index on the date, so the data is not regenerated on every query.

Comment: @MrZach The calendar can exist farther into the future, you would just add `where v_Weeks.[Start] < dateadd(year,2,getdate())`to your query like you do in your view.